# URl object is not created in IE when address bar is escaped

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've came across a weird issue...

with internet explorer, version 11 in my case, browsing to:
http://bus.gov.il/WebForms/wfrmLuz.aspx?SugTransfer=0&company=1&language=he&RovaDest=2109&DateTokef=09/07/2017&title=09/07/2017%20-%20%u05D9%u05D5%u05DD%20%u05D0&RovaSrc=3195&DayOrder=1&FromYeshuv=%u05E8%u05E2%u05E0%u05E0%u05D4&FromRova=%u05E8%u05E2%u05E0%u05E0%u05D4%20%u05DE%u05E1%u05D5%u05E3%20%u05D0%u05D5%u05D8%u05D5%u05D1%u05D5%u05E1%u05D9%u05DD&ToYeshuv=%u05EA%u05DC%20%u05D0%u05D1%u05D9%u05D1%20%u05D9%u05E4%u05D5&ToRova=%u05EA%u05DC-%u05D0%u05D1%u05D9%u05D1%20%u05EA%u05D7%u05E0%u05D4%20%u05DE%u05E8%u05DB%u05D6%u05D9%u05EA%20%u05D7%u05D3%u05E9%u05D4&hour=&width=1024

and then in the dev-tools console, running this command:
window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["string"]))

results with an error.
This doesn't happen for other sites...
Does anyone have an idea what's going on? is this yet an issue with IE?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me!
Tools>Internet Options>Security tab,
1. Click "Reset all zones to default"
2. Select the Trusted Sites icon, "Sites" button, remove the domain bus.gov.il from your list.... (the Trusted sites zone actually has a lower security profile than the Internet zone... IE has a security zone setting preventing navigation into a zone of lower integrity... https (the secure protocol) works just as well in any IE security zone.... The IE trusted sites list is mostly used by Enterprise users to allow navigation to business partner portals... there should be no need for home users to add sites to the IE Trusted sites list. Remove any other hosts from your IE Trusted sites lists. Ensure that Tools>Smart screen filter is turned on to prevent phishing attacks. https works in any IE security zone(your data is encrypted)

That site uses Flash. Ensure that IE's ActiveX filtering is turned off before you visit the site (Tools>ActiveX filtering).

Comment: your answer doesn't answer by question... thank anyway